# Invalid Hostname on IIS Express in local network

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

When I start my IIS-Express from Visual Studio I can connect to my website and everything works fine. 
I wanted to make my website accessible from the local network so i tried the following:

Started Visual Studio(2019 community edition) as admin

Changed the: 
launchSettings.json

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1313/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Skilliam": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1313/"
    }
  }
}
```

applicationhost.config

```
     <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>      
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1313:localhost" />               
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1313:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

firewall

[image]

After all this changes I still get the "Invalid Hostname", when trying to connect from different devices in my network.

Comment: "After all this changes I still get the "Invalid Hostname", when trying to connect from different devices in my network." What's the URL you use when connecting from other devices?

Comment: the local ip address+port 1313 of the pc where the iis server runs